# Logic App to call Azure SQL stored procedure passing datetime param

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple stored procedure in an Azure SQL database that takes a single param of type `datetime`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteLogRecs]
    (@pSinceBefore datetime)
```

I'd like to call this from an Azure Logic App passing a date value of Now -3 days, so I have the following action:

```
"Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "pSinceBefore": "@{convertFromUtc(addDays(utcNow(),-3),'GMT Standard Time')}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sqldw']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
```

My problem is, I get the following error:

> "status": 400,
> "message": "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.\r\nclientRequestId: dbbd2502-899f-4812-a942-4c11bbed4c1b",
> "error": {
> "message": "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime."

[image]

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: is your input nvarchar from logic app? Try to change it to datetime

Comment: Your value is accurate to 1/1000000 of a second, `datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 of a second; it won't accept a string value like that as it can't store it. Perhaps you should be using a `datetime2(7)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to bodge this by changing the type of the stored procedure parameter to a string and using the following formatting from the logic app:

```
"Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "pSinceBefore": "@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-3),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"
                    },
```